# Unable to edit or set masterpage in SP2010 site (migrated from wss 3.0)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, migration, wss, sharepoint-designer, master-pages

I just migrated sharepoint site from wss 3.0 to SP2010 foundation.

The site is not rendering while the "lists" are visible. I want to open and edit the masterpage for the site first.

Opened site using Sharepoint designer 2010 and tried to open masterpage but kept on saying "master page editing disabled for the site. contact ...".

I am the site collection admin, farm admin etc and have all privileges.

Went to central admin, and SPD settings, switched to the web-application and everything was already ticked and I ticked again and saved. Did IISRESET as well.

I opened the URL 
http://f2010:81/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx

and it showed me all masterpages. Default.master has value of "3" in compatible UI versions while minial and v4.master have 4.

I can't open the default.master (or any masterpage including v4) from here. I can't even set any masterpage as default.

Below URL gives me 'unexpected error'.
http://f2010:81/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

Please suggest